# Oracle code incorrect

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SQL> create table Drugs (
  2  DrugNumber smallint primary key,
  3  DrugMarketName varchar(40),
  4  DrugGenericName varchar(40),
  5  PackSize smallint,
  6  UnitCost numeric(7,2),
  7  foreign key (DrugSupplierNumber) references Drug_Suppliers (DrugSupplierNumber) );
foreign key (DrugSupplierNumber) references Drug_Suppliers (DrugSupplierNumber)
)
             *
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-00904: "DRUGSUPPLIERNUMBER": invalid identifier
```

Comment: I see no DrugSupplierNumber column in your table definition for Drugs.  Oracle agrees with me - add one.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle complains (correctly) that you don't have a column DrugSupplierNumber in your table definition.
Either get rid of the "foreign key", or create a normal column DrugSupplierNumber and add the constraint afterwards; example for v1:

```
create table Drugs (
  DrugNumber smallint primary key,
  DrugMarketName varchar(40),
  DrugGenericName varchar(40),
  PackSize smallint,
  UnitCost numeric(7,2),
  DrugSupplierNumber references Drug_Suppliers (DrugSupplierNumber) 
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to create a foreign key constraint that involves a column `DrugSupplierNumber` that is not part of the table.  Either you don't want to create the foreign key on this table or you want to add a `DrugSupplierNumber` column to this table or you want to reference one of the other columns in this table in your constraint.  My guess is that you just forgot to add the `DrugSupplierNumber` column to the table definition.

Though it is syntactically valid, it is very unlikely that declaring columns in an Oracle table as `smallint` is doing what you want.  That is an alias for a `NUMBER(38)` so it doesn't provide any (reasonable) sort of upper bound like you would expect if you're coming from a non-Oracle database.

```
SQL> create table foo( col1 smallint );

Table created.

SQL> desc foo
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COL1                                               NUMBER(38)
```

Additionally, in Oracle, it would be much more conventional to declare string columns as `VARCHAR2` rather than `VARCHAR` and to declare the `UnitCost` column as `NUMBER(7,2)` rather than `NUMERIC(7,2)`.